# Find distinct files with python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to use python to find distinct files among 1000 files. In these files, most of strings are the same.

```
distinct = []
line_list = []
for i in range(1,1001,1):
    file_name = str(i) + ".lp"
    f = open(file_name, "w+")
    objFunction()
    f.write("Subject To\n")
    constraintBuild(raw_list)
    posConstraint()
    f.write("End\n")
    f.close()
    output_name = "output_" + str(i) + ".txt"
    # command = str(i) + ".lp -o " + output_name
    # os.system("glpsol --lp " + command)
    f = open(output_name, "rb")
    # for j in range(88,106):
    lines = f.read()
    line_list.append(lines)
```

In this part of code, I was building 1000 `.lp` files and 1000 `output` files. Now I need to find distinct `output` ones. As I said, there are many same strings in these 1000 output files, only a part of them can be different.

I am wondering how to achieve this goal.

Comment: Can you give an example of expected output please?

Comment: @Linden The expected output should be 3 or 4 files in the 1000 `output` files. Now I can use `append` to generate all lines of 1000 files into a list but fail to find the distinct ones.

Comment: Take a look at [`difflib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/difflib.html) and [`filecmp`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/filecmp.html) which are builtin libraries for this purpose .. files can differ in many ways (content, name, permissions..)

Comment: Can you clarify how the code shown relates to the problem? What's the point of the fist ``f`` – it seems the same data is written to each. What do ``objFunction``, ``constraintBuild`` and ``posConstraint`` have to do with the issue?

Comment: @MisterMiyagi The first `f` is to open and write something into the files. `objFunction`, `constraintBuild` and `posConstraint` are among the contents in these files. Now I've already had this files. The final step is to tell how many distinct output are there.

Answer (score 0):

The idea is to keep the file name and file content in the same data struct and use set to remove duplicates (**based on file content**):

```
class File:
    def __init__(self, name, content):
        self.name = name
        self.content = content

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self.content == other.content

    def __hash__(self):
        return hash(self.content)

    def __repr__(self):
        return f'{self.name} -> {self.content}'


files = [File('f1', 'qaz'), File('f3', 'qaz'), File('f38', 'qaz12')]
files_set = set(files)
print(files_set)
```

output

```
{f1 -> qaz, f38 -> qaz12}
```

Comment: I tried this approach with `line_list = set(line_list)` but the `print(len(line_list))` still returns `1000`

Comment: As you can see in the example above, it  works. So you are doing something different. Isnt it? Question: Are those text files?

Comment: Yes, they are `.txt` files